# Find conditions on $f,g$ $E[ \langle g(X), f(X) \rangle ] \ge \langle E[ g(X)], E[f(X)] \rangle $ (i.e., FKG inequality for multivariate functions))

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, expected-value

The classical FKG inequality states that for two non-decreasing function $f,g: R \to R$ we have that
\begin{align}
E[ f(X)  g(X) ] \ge E[f(X) ] E[g(X)]
 \end{align}

I am interested in understanding what is the generalization of this to the following multivariate setting:  Consider two functions $f,g: R^n \to R^n$.  We want to show the following inequality:
\begin{align}
E[ \langle  g(X),  f(X) \rangle ] \ge   \langle  E[  g(X)],  E[f(X)] \rangle ]
\end{align}

The issue is that I am not sure what is proper assumption that we can make about $f$ and $g$ since defining increasing function in the multivariate setting is not straight forward.

Perhaps an easy case to consider is when one of the function is a linear
\begin{align}
E[ \langle  g(X),  A X \rangle ] \ge   \langle  E[  g(X)],  E[ A X] \rangle 
\end{align}
where $A$ is symmetric positive definite matrix (i.e., so that $f(x) = Ax$ is 'increasing').

Comment: Suggestion: since in one dimension an increasing function is the derivative of  a convex function , for $n\geq  2$ assume that $f$ is the gradient of a convex function $F$ on $R^n$. Your example was $F=x^TAX/2$ with $A$ semi positive definite. Sorry to be busy today for investigating.

Answer (score 1):

The natural definition of increasing function $f: R^n\rightarrow R^n$ is $$\langle x-y, f(x)-f(y)\rangle \geq 0$$for all $x,y$ which is the case when $f$ is the gradient of a convex function since in this case
$$\langle x-y, f(x)-f(y)\rangle =\int_0^1\langle x-y, A(t)(x-y)\rangle dt $$ where $A(t)=f'(y+t(x-y)) $ is semipositive definite.

However, even is this favorable case where $f$ and $g$ are the gradients of convex functions, and denoting $B(s)=g'(y+s(x-y)) $ I have doubt that  the Tchebychef trick, which was to use

$$\langle g(x)-g(y), f(x)-f(y)\rangle \geq 0$$ works here since

$$\langle g(x)-g(y), f(x)-f(y)\rangle $$$$=
\int_0^1\int_0^1\langle B(s)(x-y),A(t)(x-y)\rangle dsdt$$ does not seem positive (recall that $AB+BA$ is not necessarily semi positive definite when $A$ and $B$ are, unless I am mistaken).

Comment: Thanks for starting this discussion. Yeah, in general $AB+ BA$ is not positive definite. However, the trace of it is positive. Also it has at least one positive eigenvalue.  I am not sure if these are helpful.